# C++ merging linked list issue

Tags: c++, linked-list, visual-studio-2019

So I'm a beginner to C++ and I have a school project to create a linked list and I'm working on the merge method right now and I'm not sure why it's not working. I identified the problem to be in the second if in the while loop where instead of changing the head_ list node it's changing the list1 list and I don't know why it's doing that

```
template <typename T>
bool List342<T>::Merge(const List342<T>& list1) {
    if (head_ == nullptr) {
        head_ = list1.head_;
        return true;
    }
    if (list1.head_ == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    Node<T>* l1_ptr = list1.head_;
    Node<T>* head_ptr = head_;
    while (l1_ptr != nullptr && head_ptr != nullptr) {
        if (*head_ptr->data == *l1_ptr->data) {
            l1_ptr = l1_ptr->next;
            head_ptr = head_ptr->next;
        }
        else if (*head_ptr->data <= *l1_ptr->data) {
            Node<T>* temp = head_ptr->next;
            head_ptr->next = l1_ptr;
            l1_ptr->next = temp;
            l1_ptr = l1_ptr->next;
            head_ptr = head_ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You misspelled changing in two different ways : )

Comment: Can you elaborate on merging? Do you have two sorted lists and want to create a sorted one with their union?

Comment: yes both the head_ and the list1 are sorted and head_ is a pointer to the start of the list in the object and we want to take everything from list1 and put it into head_ with it still being sorted and NO duplicates

Comment: It looks like you should be creating new nodes then (instead of shallow copying)

Comment: that would be an easier option but our professor want to make our life harder and doesn't wants us to allocate new memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224573/discussion-between-nikhil-alapati-and-kostas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find working with linked lists easier with references and recursion over the list iterators. This version makes sure the second linked list is left in a valid state (though maybe changed), and no new memory is allocated.

```
template <class T>
bool List342<T>::Merge(List342<T>& list1) {
  merge(head_, list1.head_);
}

template <class T>
void merge(List342<T>::Node*& head, List342<T>::Node*& head_o) {
  if (head_o == nullptr)
      return;

  if (head == nullptr) {
    head = head_o;
    head_o = nullptr;
    return;
  }

  if (*head->data <= *head_o->data) {
    merge(head->next, head_o);
  } else {
    // steal Node from right list1                                                                                             
    auto* next = head->next;
    auto* next_o = head_o->next;
    head->next = head_o;
    head_o->next = next;
    head_o = next_o; // this works because head_o is a reference                                                               
    merge(head->next, head_o);
  }
}
```

I think this kind of code makes it much easier to argue about what happens in each case. Let me know if you have questions.